# CloudFront to redirect URL

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have CloudFront setup for `domain.com` to server static contents from S3 and everything else from ELB -> EC2

Want to setup permanent redirect for `domain.ca` to `domain.com`. Haw can I do this in CloudFront ?

Is Lambda@Edge efficient way ? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/handling-redirectsedge-part1/

Comment: This blog post might be helpful https://medium.com/@chrispointon/redirecting-non-www-to-www-website-in-aws-cloudfront-658d97764b42.

Comment: Can't you just define a `CNAME` to make them equivalent?